# How to dynamically create new class implementing some interface and instantiate it?

Tags: java, reflection, instantiation, java-compiler-api

Is it possible to compose new class at runtime in Java?

What are the means for that? Refection? Compiler API?

I can do

```
package tests;

public class TryReflection02 {

    interface A {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object o = new A() {};

        System.out.println( o.toString() );

        o = A.class.newInstance() // exception

    }

}
```

Can I do the same having `A.class` value?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? What you create with `o` is basically an anonymous class

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: @fge I know; hot do this with reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. `A` is an interface, and only classes can be instantiated.

What you *can* do is to use a library/helper that uses some trickery to create a class that implements the interface and instantiates *that*. The JDK's [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class contains static methods to do just that. There are also tools that can do it which are custom-geared for test-related use cases: [mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/), for instance.

These tools do exactly what you hint at in this question's title: rather than instantiating the interface, they generate a new class that implements the interface, and then instantiate that class.